# is ndisgtk running correctly?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, bug-reporting, ndiswrapper, ubuntu-bug

I reported a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndiswrapper/+bug/1152134), which was marked as a duplicate of another bug, and then a [duplicate of another bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndiswrapper/+bug/1023645) -- which is fine, I think it is a duplicate.

First off, the architecture is different.  The original bug, #1023645, is `Architecture: amd64` while the bug I reported is `Architecture: i386` and so it I feel I should question as to whether it should be separate.

In any event, what should I do in order to use ndiswrapper?  It **looks** to me that ndiswrapper is installed:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ aptitude search ndiswrapper
i   ndiswrapper-common                  - Common scripts required to use the utilities 
i   ndiswrapper-dkms                    - Source for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel modul
v   ndiswrapper-modules-1.9             -                                              
i   ndiswrapper-source                  - Source for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel modul
i   ndiswrapper-utils-1.9               - Userspace utilities for the ndiswrapper Linux
thufir@dur:~$
```

I'm only using xfce, but seem able to bring up `ndisgtk` as so:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo ndisgtk

(ndisgtk:4797): libglade-WARNING **: Could not load support for `gnome': libgnome.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/ndisgtk:127: GtkWarning: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.ZZ68TW': No such file or directory
  gtk.main()
/usr/sbin/ndisgtk:127: GtkWarning: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: No such file or directory
  gtk.main()
thufir@dur:~$
```

Does the fact that ndisgtk runs indicate that everything is ok?

Answer (score 1):

for 12.10 ndiswrapper is currently only working with revision 1.58rc1 (since Oct 2012)
for this version ndisgtk must not be installed afterwards in order to avoid complications.

[Source (german)](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wlan-pci-wird-nicht-bei-jedem-start-erkannt/#post-3842662)

Comment: pardon, can you explain that a bit more please?

Comment: sorry for beeing a bit sparing with words:
i have no information about the reason problems occur with the version from the repositorties and 12.10

But what I can tell you is that my ndiswrapper from the repos failed to work and crashed with "FATAL: module ndisgtk not present" or something like that, ndisgtk didn't react at all in my case.

Comment: to prove wheter ndiswrapper works correctly:
what does 
sudo modprobe ndisgtk tell you?